# Load images from a given directory gives: Not allowed to load local resource: <distorted path> ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

This question is connected to my [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74239658/display-all-images-in-a-given-directory-without-using-nodejs-asp-net-core), I need to display a couple of images from a given directory. In the previous question, I approached it from the JavaScript side. I thought about it and came to the conclusion that if it can be done by JavaScript why it can't be done by C#? So I search a bit and came up with a way to get all of the files inside a directory.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Project5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string Directory = @"SOME PATH"
            string[] Paths = Directory.GetFiles(Directory);

            foreach(var Path in Paths)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This returned the path to each file that was in that directory. But when I tried putting that code inside the ASP.NET Core project, it just throws an error.

Code:

```
@using System.IO;

@{ 
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(_Data.path); // _Data.path - A path to the directory. The path is stored on a SQL server, from the controller, I extract the path with some other data and move it to the HTML.
    foreach (var file in filePaths)
        {
            <script> console.log('@file');</script>
            <img src="@file" />
        }
}
```

**Error**:

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/User/source/repos/%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8FSvivaTeamVersion3%20-%20%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A7/SvivaTeamVersion3/wwwroot/Files/Road_Problems/Accident/gM80oFarPLSnSVbp906JVwHxDXi2czTsdidOvFxnGTymN96cE6iQTWTtFKwRgiPZ/Banner%20template.jpg

As you can see, the error says that it's not allowed to load the image, that because the path is distorted.

When I put the path in the regular program (the first code) it comes out as usual, but when I do that in the ASP.NET Core project it's not the same.

**My question**: why is this happening and how can it be fixed? I want it to return the correct path and just load the images as usual.

## Additional info

`Program.CS`

```
namespace SvivaTeamVersion3
{
    public class AdministrationController
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) => {
            logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                logging.AddConsole();
                logging.AddDebug();
                logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
                logging.AddNLog();
            }).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

### Edit:

So, to get to the images I had to find a way to make the path look like that: `~/Files/Fodlers/image` so I've written this code that gets the path and the images.

```
@using System.IO;
@using System.Linq;
@using System.Collections.Generic;

@{
    var path = _Data.path;
    var ImgPath = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("Files") - 1, (path.Length - (path.LastIndexOf("Files") - 1)));

    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path); // _Data.path
    foreach (var file in filePaths)
    {
        var temp = file;

        List<string> set1 = path.Split('\\').Distinct().ToList();
        List<string> set2 = temp.Split('\\').Distinct().ToList();

        var diff = set2.Count() > set1.Count() ? set2.Except(set1).ToList() : set1.Except(set2).ToList();

        <img src="~/@ImgPath/@string.Join("", diff)" />
    }
}
```

when I used it in a regular project it all worked fine with a regular path but in here in the line `List<string> set1 = Convert.ToString(path).Split(@"\").Distinct().ToList();` I get an error `RuntimeBinderException: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Distinct'` the line for `set1` does not work but the line for `set2` works just fine. I don't know why but I can also see a color difference in the same code. [image: screenshot of the code]

Comment: No, the path is not distorted, it is just that some characters are encoded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not allowed to load local resource: file:// in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61186092/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-file-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: Where does your directory located within your project? Does your project has the static file reference on your program.cs file? In addition, could you please share your `program.cs` details as well.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron The folder system works like that, we have 'Files' directory inside wwwroot, and inside it, I have 3 more subfolders each subfolder has some subfolders, and each subfolder has more subfolders that contain the images.

Yes, confusing, I am sorry, I'll give an example

Path example: `C:\Users\User\source\repos\‏‏SvivaTeamVersion3 - עותק\SvivaTeamVersion3\wwwroot\Files\Road_Problems\Accident\gM80oFarPLSnSVbp906JVwHxDXi2czTsdidOvFxnGTymN96cE6iQTWTtFKwRgiPZ\Banner template.jpg`

Added the `Program.cs` Now.

Comment: have you tried with a shorted path, and also no spaces in file name, something like: C:\uploads\images\banner-template.jpg

Comment: @KARIMYassine not possible.

Comment: I was assuming something like. Your path is too long and this is cusing the issue. To troubleshoot this, first, please check with shortest path if that works. If that works as expected then you proceed further. Therefore, I think we should point the trouble first.

Comment: Doesn't work with a shorter path,


New path I gave just for example: C:\Users\User\Desktop\f1\f2\ with 1 image in it.


Error Not allowed to load local resource: `file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/f1/f2/_methode_sundaytimes_prod_web_bin_ce3beda8-87ef-11eb-a305-6c8dc51a72e0.jpg`

Comment: If I remove the `file:///` it'll work.. 

How the `file:///` got there and how to remove it?

Comment: The file is in the USER folder and can only be accessed by the owner and an Admin.